# Appending multiple elements to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a function that extracts a number of variables from zillow. I used a lambda function to append the returned values to a dataframe. I am wondering if there is a faster way to return all the variables and append them to the dataframe instead of individually.

Here is my code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse,parseString
import xml.dom.minidom
import requests
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l_zwsid='' 

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def getElementValue(p_dom,p_element):
    if len(p_dom.getElementsByTagName(p_element)) > 0:
       l_value=p_dom.getElementsByTagName(p_element)[0]
       return(l_value.firstChild.data)
    else:
       l_value='NaN'
       return(l_value)

def getData(l_zwsid, a_addr, a_zip):
    try:
        l_url='http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id='+l_zwsid+'&address='+a_addr+'&citystatezip='+a_zip
        xml=requests.get(l_url)
        dom=parseString(xml.text)

        responses=dom.getElementsByTagName('response')

        zpid=getElementValue(dom,'zpid')
        usecode=getElementValue(dom,'useCode')
        taxyear=getElementValue(dom,'taxAssessmentYear')
        tax=getElementValue(dom,'taxAssessment')
        yearbuilt=getElementValue(dom,'yearBuilt')
        sqft=getElementValue(dom,'finishedSqFt')
        lotsize=getElementValue(dom,'lotSizeSqFt')
        bathrooms=getElementValue(dom,'bathrooms')
        bedrooms=getElementValue(dom,'bedrooms')
        totalrooms=getElementValue(dom,'totalRooms')
        lastSale=getElementValue(dom,'lastSoldDate')
        lastPrice=getElementValue(dom,'lastSoldPrice')
        latitude=getElementValue(dom, 'latitude')
        longitude=getElementValue(dom, 'longitude')

        for response in responses:
            addresses=response.getElementsByTagName('address')
            for addr in addresses:
                street=getElementValue(addr,'street')
                zipcode=getElementValue(addr,'zipcode')

            zestimates=response.getElementsByTagName('zestimate')
            for zest in zestimates:
                amt=getElementValue(zest,'amount')
                lastupdate=getElementValue(zest,'last-updated')
                valranges=zest.getElementsByTagName('valuationRange')
                for val in valranges:
                    low=getElementValue(val,'low')
                    high=getElementValue(val,'high')
        return longitude, latitude
    except AttributeError:
        return None

df['Longtitude'] = df.apply(lambda row: getData(l_zwsid, row['Street'], row['Zip']), axis = 1)
df['Latitude'] = df.apply(lambda row: getData(l_zwsid, row['Street'], row['Zip']), axis = 1)
```

This currently does not work because the new columns will contain both the longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getData` function returns a tuple, which is why both columns have both lat and lon. One workaround could be to parameterise this function as follows:

```
def getData(l_zwsid, a_addr, a_zip, axis='lat'):
    valid = ['lat', 'lon']
    if axis not in valid:
        raise ValueError(f'axis must be one of {valid}')
    ...
    if axis == 'lat':
        return latitude
    else:
        return longitude
```

This <strike>won't improve efficiency</strike> will make it even slower, however. Your main overhead is coming from making API calls for every row in the DataFrame, so you are constrained by network performance.

Comment: I see, do you know what approach I should use to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

- You can make your `getData` function return a string which contains comma separated values of all the elements
- Append this csv string as `ALL_TEXT`column in the dataframe `df`
- Split the column `ALL_TEXT` into multiple columns (Lat, long, zipcode, street etc)

  ```
  def split_into_columns(text):

      required_columns = ['Latitude', 'Longtitude', 'Zipcode']
      columns_value_list = text['ALL_TEXT'].split(',')
      for i in range(len(required_columns)):
      text[required_columns[i]] = columns_value_list[i]

      return text

  df= pd.DataFrame([ ['11.49, 12.56, 9823A'], ['14.02, 15.29, 9674B'] ], columns=['ALL_TEXT'])  

  updated_df = df.apply(split_into_columns, axis=1)
  ```

> df

```
    ALL_TEXT
0   11.49, 12.56, 9823A
1   14.02, 15.29, 9674B
```

> updated_df

```
   ALL_TEXT              Latitude  Longtitude Zipcode
0   11.49, 12.56, 9823A  11.49     12.56       9823A
1   14.02, 15.29, 9674B  14.02     15.29       9674B
```

Comment: Could you explain further how I would modify my getData() function?